# How do I convert a list of arbitrary values into a subquery that can be used in a join

Tags: sql, postgresql, list, join

I want to join a list of values with table rows in SQL.

Shortly, I have a list of elements and I want to `join` this element with a given table.

For example, my list is `(1,3,5,100,200,700)` and the `table` is:

```
id | val
 1 |  a
 2 |  b
 3 |  c
 4 |  d
100|  e
200|  f
```

I know how to do that with `in` clause:

```
 SELECT * FROM table 
 WHERE id IN(list)
```

Unfortunately, in my situation (very-very long list) I cannot use `in` clause and required using `join` with that list.

How to convert list (in the format that "in" can deal with) to something that can be joined.

**Important constraint:** I don't have writing permissions in the database so answers like "*write this list into new table and then join them*" - don't help me. Generally, I need to use this practice hundreds times in the code, so create a new table for every query not feasible even I have writing permissions.

Can you help me, please?

Comment: What form is that list? If you have to join it, it should be in a table

Comment: This is the focus of the question - how to convert list (in the format that "in" can deal with) to something that can be joined.

Comment: You could for example; create a temporary table that has a single column holding your entire list and make use of either `EXISTS` or an `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that list is a string, you can e.g. replace the parentheses with curly braces and cast it to an array:

```
where id = any('{1,3,5,100,200,700}'::int[])
```

Or if you can't change the input:

```
where id = any(translate('(1,3,5,100,200,700)', '()', '{}')::int[])
```

The same approach can be used for joining:

```
select mt.*
from my_table mt
  join unnest('{1,3,5,100,200,700}'::int[]) as x(id) on x.id = mt.id
```

But those two solutions aren't the same: if the list contains duplicates the join will return duplicate rows as well. The `id = any()` condition will not do that.

Comment: Thx. It looks like what I try to use. What is the meaning of the *::int[]*? If my list of strings, need I change that?

Comment: That's a cast to an integer array. As your list contains numbers, I assumed your `id` column is an integer as well

Comment: but if my id column is string type, what should I do?

Comment: The real question is then: why are you storing numbers as strings? That's a really bad idea. But if you have to work with that broken design, cast it to a text array `::text[]`

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. In a similar case, I have a list like: ```('a', 'b', 'c', 'f')``` and the id column include other string in this form.

Comment: Is there a limit about the length of "any" ? it's supposed to be for million arguments as well?

Comment: Well a single string can not exceed 1GB. But it sounds as if there is something seriously wrong in your overall design if you need to pass millions of values for such a condition. Where do those values come from?

Comment: The values came from another application. The values extracted from pandas dataframe (that created locality) and I need to join them with the rows in the database server.